# Android Crash: NullPointerException on Fragment CreateView (UnknowSource)

Tags: android, android-fragments, view, nullpointerexception, oncreate

I receive a NullPointerException crash report in Android Developer Console. The stack trace shows:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp/com.myapp.PropDisplayActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2067)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2092)
    .... 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.myapp.fragments.r.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.myapp.fragments.r.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:829)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
    ....
```

Is there any way to see the full stack trace from Crash Report in Android Developer Console?

I believe this only happen to a certain Android device/version. What could possibly the NullPointerException (Unknown Source) in CreateView error be?

I've tried to check my code for null pointer possibility and currently, I have no idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Java: Fragments returning null view in onCreateView()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20086303/android-java-fragments-returning-null-view-in-oncreateview)

Comment: Decode the obfuscated stacktrace...  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html